# Getting an AttributeError on posting the data to database having foriegnkey relation in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having a users and furniture table I want to store the furniture id selected by the user in the users table through the form the furniture field is having the foreign key relationship with the furniture table while posting I am getting this error
My models.py is:

```
class furniture(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    phrase=models.CharField(max_length=60,default='111111')



class users(models.Model):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goals)
    style = models.ManyToManyField(designs)
    furniture = models.ForeignKey(furniture,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My views.py :

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        room = request.POST['room']
        g=goal=request.POST['goal']
        g = g.split(',')
        s=style=request.POST['style']
        s=s.split(',')
        furniture=request.POST['furniture']
        user = users(password=password,email=email)
        user.room=rooms.objects.get(pk=room)
        goal = goals.objects.filter(pk__in=g)
        style = designs.objects.filter(pk__in=s)
        request.encoding = 'koi8-r'
        user.furniture = furniture.objects.all()
        user.save()
        user.goal.add(*goal)
        user.style.add(*style)
        return render(request,'home.html')
```

My form.html is:

```
<div class="card-body">
              <form action="{% url 'car:user_register' %}" method="POST"  >
              {% csrf_token %}

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="room" id="name" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >
                <input type="text" name="goal" id="goal" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >
                <input type="text" name="style" id="style" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >

                <input type="number" name="furniture" id="furniture" value=" ">
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Register" style="background-color:#000080;" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
              <div class="rangeslider">
              </div>
            </form>
```

Error is:[image]

With the above the room id is storing but why the furniture id is not storing please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had got an answer the form field name and the table name should not be equal so I changed the form field name it worked.